# Is possible to hide (to not paint) some text of any JTextComponent?

Tags: java, gate

I have a JTextArea (which I could not change) and I want to implement similar behaviour like a table has (allow to hide some columns and rows). Currently I have to reload to do that (to change content of JTextArea). Is possible to do that (anyhow)?

**More info to understand**

I am trying to rewrite the DocumentView in the Gate Developer to allow user to show and hide columns and rows. Unfortunately, Gate Developer is 'document based' so majority of functionality counts with offsets and does not know about columns or rows (for example annotations and their highlights). Therefore I have to recreate new document with new annotations (and others) in the reload process before I return it on the screen.

**Example**

Have a JTextArea with this content:

```
00 01 02

10 11 12

20 21 22

30 31 32
```

User want to hide column indexed by 1. => I have to parse text and remove the second item from each row and after that set text to JTextArea.

Result:

```
00 02

10 12

20 22

30 32
```

I do not want to change text (reload process) but I want to tell JTextArea to not draw that part. Try to imagine like a JTable without borders. JTable allows to drag with columns and totaly hide one column by another but the column is still there.

Comment: If you do not want to change the text, how would you tell the UI class what is not to be displayed? In other words, what type of functionality are you expecting?

Comment: What about a JTable without grid lines, a TableModel where you can dynamically remove a column? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443008/adding-columns-to-jtable-dynamically

Comment: 1) I want to decide in paintComponent which part of text will be painted. I think that answer below is too close what I need.

Comment: 2) I can not use JTable because I need to have whole text as a document because other components of the GATE Developer counts with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JTextPane`.

Then you can either use a StyledDocument, or easier:

Then you can use HTML and CSS. By switching the style, say of a CSS class you can remove its rendering.

```
<html>
<p>
<span class='col0'>...</span>
<span class='col1'>...</span>
<span class='col2'>...</span>
</p>
```

And then something like

```
HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit())textpane.getEditorKit(kit);

StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
styleSheet.addRule(".col0 {...}");
```

Comment: Would this not need a change to the text? OP says they don't want to change the text

Comment: @MiserableVariable the text must be different, but hiding could be done by changing the style. Unfortunately I have no ready code snippet for that.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am not sure if it will be compatible with other GATE components but I think it is good way. But I just tried it and I am not able to set style to hide a tag. Example: styleSheet.addRule("div {color: #ff0000; visibility:hidden; display:none; }"); - changes color but does not hide a div. I tried a lot of ways but I can not figure out how to do that.