# Adding data in Jtable from multiple arrays

Tags: java, jtable

I have two list, the first list contains the employee name and the second list contains the employee ID. In my jtable I have two columns "Name" and "ID". Is there any way to add data column wise in the jtable column wise?

```
public static ArrayList <String> Name = new ArrayList <String>();
public static ArrayList <Double> ID = new ArrayList <Double>();
String[] columns = {"Name","ID"};
JTable table = new JTable(Columns,0);
//What to enter here
```

I have read many articles which says that in jtable you can add data row wise only. But in my case the arrays do not contains information row wise. Also I have tried to merge both the rows in a single list but that also do not solve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First off consider using a class or Dictionary to store your values instead. Okay let me dive into how to solve it using row and column iteration:

**Row Iteration**

I'm going to explain how to solve the problem using row iteration first because it's recommended (column iteration below). You can use a for loop to iterate through them both and add the values at the same time. For example:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
for (int i = 0; i < Name.size(); i++) {
    Object[] o = new Object[2];
    o[0] = Name.get(i);
    if(i<ID.size())
    {
        o[1] = ID.get(i);
    }
    model.addRow(o);
}
model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
table.setModel(model);
```

Also consider using an `int` for IDs instead.

**Column Iteration**

But if you really want to use column iteration, check out this link:

[Adding Columns to JTable dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443008/adding-columns-to-jtable-dynamically)

Basically how it is explained in that post is that you need to add the column to the model and then add the object array with the values to the model.

```
model.addColumn("ID", ID.toArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response :) In case of row iteration where are you adding the object array. In case of column iteration "ID" array has to be converted in obect [] first i guess.

Comment: If using `DefaultTableModel`, you can also simply use `model.addColumn("ID", ID.toArray());` and `model.addColumn("Name", Name.toArray());`

Comment: @Mani my pleasure. Sorry forgot to add the `toArray()`, Enwired beat me to the punch, I'll edit the answer to reflect the refinement :)

Comment: @Enwired: Thanks a lot. This was what i wanted. :)

Comment: Unfortunately due to less credits i cannot upvote. But thnks a lot to both. :)

Comment: @Mani no problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm new here myself, good luck and I wish all the best.