# How to insert a foreign key column in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two tables:

1. Doctor
2. Doc Category

[image: Doc Category table iddoccategory is foreign key in Doctor Table]

[image: Doctor Table fidcategory is foreign key]

[image: add to doctor table]

I want to insert a foreign key in place of `doccategory`

Comment: Please post code samples to clarify your scenario and add images to your question [as images](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images), not as links.

Comment: @bkis 1) *"post code samples"* Usually better to recommend a `[mre]`, chich automatically expands to [mre]. 2) It takes a higher rep. to be able to directly insert images, and that's for good reason. Many newbies don't know the appropriate time to post images rather than the text seen in the image. They even tend to post screenshots of the source code in their IDE!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the hints! Didn't know this rep. threshold. You're right, of course.

Answer (score -1):

So I think you request how to add a column in your JTable component.

Best response [found on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2443147/390462) :

```
public class TableColumnAdd {
    private static DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    private static int columnNumber = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] { "Initial Column" }, 5);
                JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Column Add");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 300);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        for (;;) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tableModel.addColumn("Column #" + columnNumber++);
                }
            });
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in the above tables i have two keys related iddoccategory is the primary key in doccategory table.in the other table fidcategory is the foreign key in table doctor. fidcategory is referenced to iddoccategory in the above form in jcombobox i have shown the doccategory name and now i want to insert a key in place of category name in doctor table